# How can I sort the Array map() function output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to sort items after using map() function. 
But the sorting must be based on a specific item's property.
Then how I can customize the index before I pass it to "key"?

Here the response from the API

```
[
  {
    "typeId": 2,
    "count": 410
  },
  {
    "typeId": 3,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "typeId": 4,
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "typeId": 5,
    "count": 21
  },
  {
    "typeId": 6,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "typeId": 7,
    "count": 80
  }
   ...
]
```

Data exploitation

```
 <div className="top-error-ctn">
  <span className="heading">Top Errors</span>
  <p>
    Sorted By Type
  </p>
  <div className="row">
     {Sometest ? (
       all.slice(0, 6).map((all, index) => {
          return <ErrorBar key={index} all={all} />;
       })
     ) : (
       <span>Nothing to see</span>
     )}
  </div>
</div>
```

Data Rendering

```
<div>
  <div className="side">
    <div>{all.typeId}</div>
  </div>
  <div className="middle">
    <div className="bar-container">
      <div className="bar-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="side right">
    <div>{all.count}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.sort()` function like below.

```js
const items = [
  {
    "typeId": 2,
    "count": 410
  },
  {
    "typeId": 3,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "typeId": 4,
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "typeId": 5,
    "count": 21
  },
  {
    "typeId": 6,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "typeId": 7,
    "count": 80
  }
];
console.log('Sort by typeId:', items.sort((a, b) => a.typeId - b.typeId));

console.log('Sort by count:', items.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort like this

```
all.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.count- a.count;
});
```